# Reformat sql to show rows where main query returns null

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Consider this sql:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( Orders.Timestamp,  '%Y%m' ) AS Period,
SUM(Price) AS 'Ordersum per month and organisation', Orders.Organisation,
(
  SELECT SUM(Amount) AS Returns
  FROM Returns
  WHERE DATE_FORMAT( Returns.Timestamp,  '%Y%m' ) = Period
  AND Returns.Organisation = Orders.Organisation
) Returns
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Period, Organisation
```

Whenever there are rows in the subquery that doesn't have an equivalent period in the main query, the row isn't displayed. The reason is that the query takes its period from the orders table, and when the period of the subquery doesn't match a period in the orders table, it simply doesn't match the query.

Is there a way to reformat this query to achieve what I want?

Sqlfiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ace715/1

Comment: What do you want to show? 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use left and right join with UNION like this:

```
SELECT 
ifnull(DATE_FORMAT( Orders.Timestamp,'%Y%m' ),DATE_FORMAT(Returns.Timestamp,'%Y%m' )) AS Period,
SUM(Price) AS 'Ordersum per month and organisation',
ifnull(Orders.Organisation,Returns.Organisation) as 'Organisation',
SUM(Amount) AS 'Returns'
FROM Orders
left JOIN Returns 
on DATE_FORMAT( Orders.Timestamp,'%Y%m' ) = DATE_FORMAT(Returns.Timestamp,  '%Y%m' ) 
and Returns.Organisation = Orders.Organisation
GROUP BY Period, Returns.Organisation, Orders.Organisation
union
select ifnull(DATE_FORMAT( Orders.Timestamp,  '%Y%m' ),DATE_FORMAT(Returns.Timestamp,'%Y%m' )) AS Period,
SUM(Price) AS 'Ordersum per month and organisation',
ifnull(Orders.Organisation,Returns.Organisation),
SUM(Amount) AS 'Returns'
FROM Orders
right JOIN Returns 
on DATE_FORMAT( Orders.Timestamp,  '%Y%m' ) = DATE_FORMAT(Returns.Timestamp, '%Y%m' ) 
and Returns.Organisation = Orders.Organisation
GROUP BY Period, Returns.Organisation, Orders.Organisation
```

Comment: Thanks, you are a genius! This is exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: @aanders77 I'm glad you could use it. Maybe there is a more efficient way using `COALESCE`, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it. About the `JOIN`, just a remark, they are usually done between `int` columns because when it's done between `varchar` or similar column types, query duration can be long and in some cases the `JOIN` may bot be working in "apparently" similar values. In this accepted answer there are some details about it in 2nd and 3rd paragraph. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916609/generally-are-string-or-varchar-fields-used-as-join-fields

Comment: I've read the concerns you refer to, none of them apply to my use case so it should be fine :-) Thanks