# How To create Dynamic dropdown list based on Country name not ID

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I need your help I found a bunch of the examples on net how to create dynamic dropdown lists based on country Id but I need to create one based on country name so what if I create table like this

```
# Create countries table
CREATE TABLE countries(
    id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    country_name varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
 
# Inserting data in countries table
INSERT INTO `countries` (`id`, `country_name`) VALUES
    (1, 'United State'),
    (2, 'India'),
    (3, 'United Kingdom');

# Create states table
CREATE TABLE states(
    id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    country_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    state_name varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
     
# Inserting data in states table
INSERT INTO `states` (`id`, `country_id`, `state_name`) VALUES
    (1, 'United State', 'California'),
    (2, 'United State', 'Florida'),
    (3, India, 'Gujarat'),
    (4, India, 'Rajasthan'),
    (5, United Kingdom, 'Teignbridge'),
    (6, United Kingdom, 'South Hams ');

# Create cities table
CREATE TABLE cities(
    id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    state_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    city_name varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
 
# Inserting data in countries table
INSERT INTO `cities` (`id`, `state_id`, `city_name`) VALUES
    (1, California, 'Alameda'),
    (2, California, 'Calexico'),
    (3, California, 'Belmont'),
    (4, Florida, 'Bartow'),
    (5, Florida, 'Lakeland'),
    (6, Florida, 'Melbourne'),
    (7, Gujarat, 'Ahmadabad'),
    (8, Gujarat, 'Rajkot'),
    (9, Gujarat, 'Surat'),
    (10, Rajasthan, 'Ajmer'),
    (11, Rajasthan, 'Bikaner'),
    (12, Rajasthan, 'Jodhpur'),
    (13, Teignbridge, 'Dawlish'),
    (14, Teignbridge, 'Ashburton'),
```

I have code based on `ID` who is `INT` but i need to be based on `int` who is `varchar`

```
<?php
// Include the database connection file
include('db_config.php');
?>
 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dynamic Dependent Select Box using jQuery, Ajax and PHP - Clue Mediator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Dynamic Dependent Select Box - <a href="https://www.cluemediator.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Clue Mediator</a></h3>
        <br />
        <form action="" method="post">
            <div class="col-md-4">
 
                <!-- Country dropdown -->
                <label for="country">Country</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="country">
                    <option value="">Select Country</option>
 <?php
 $query = "SELECT * FROM countries";
 $result = $con->query($query);
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['country_name'].'</option>';
    }
 }else{
    echo '<option value="">Country not available</option>';
 }
 ?>
                </select>
                <br />
 
                <!-- State dropdown -->
                <label for="country">State</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="state">
                    <option value="">Select State</option>
                </select>
                <br />
 
                <!-- City dropdown -->
                <label for="country">City</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="city">
                    <option value="">Select City</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Country dependent ajax
    $("#country").on("change",function(){
        var countryId = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                url :"action.php",
                type:"POST",
                cache:false,
                data:{countryId:countryId},
                success:function(data){
                    $("#state").html(data);
                    $('#city').html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
                }
        });
    });
 
    // state dependent ajax
    $("#state").on("change", function(){
        var stateId = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
                url :"action.php",
                type:"POST",
                cache:false,
                data:{stateId:stateId},
                success:function(data){
                    $("#city").html(data);
                }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

action.php

```
<?php
// Include the database connection file
include('db_config.php');
 
if (isset($_POST['countryId']) && !empty($_POST['countryId'])) {
    // Fetch state name base on country id
    $query = "SELECT *  
                FROM states 
                WHERE country_id = ".$_POST['countryId'];
    $result = $con->query($query);
 
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo '<option value="">Select State</option>';
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['state_name'].'</option>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option value="">State not available</option>';
    }
} elseif(isset($_POST['stateId']) && !empty($_POST['stateId'])) {
 
    // Fetch city name base on state id
    $query = "SELECT *  
                FROM cities     
                WHERE state_id = ".$_POST['stateId'];
    $result = $con->query($query);
 
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo '<option value="">Select city</option>';
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['city_name'].'</option>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option value="">City not available</option>';
    }
}
?>
```

so what to change on this code to have search based on `varchar ID` I am still new at this so excuse me for my ignorance

```
# Create states table
CREATE TABLE states(
id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
country_id int(11) NOT NULL,
state_name varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
 

    # Inserting data in states table
    INSERT INTO `states` (`id`, `country_id`, `state_name`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 'California'),
    (2, 1, 'Florida'),
    (3, 2, 'Gujarat'),
    (4, 2, 'Rajasthan'),
    (5, 3, 'Teignbridge'),
    (6, 3, 'South Hams ');
```

this is the original table

Comment: Borrowing code from the web is how lots of people start BUT you have to look at it, work out what its doing and how it works, maybe even check a few things with the MANUAL. Otherwise you could be adding any old rubbish to your code

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: I was trying for couple of days and that is the main reason why I asked for your help because i didn't get any result

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? Also, be warned that your queries are widely open for SQL injection - have a look at prepared statements to write secure queries

Comment: I think this may just be your confusion. In the form you click on the Country name in the dropdown and it passes the `id` of the country to the query. Thats what you want to happen right?

Comment: Ahh I assume what you changed was this `(1, 'United State', 'California'),` from this `(1, 1, 'California'),` If thats the case DONT. Its works best with `(1, 1, 'California'),`

Comment: I posted the original table and I will not use this data this was just example data and whit this kind of  search i can easier create insert statement that is why I decided  on this approach

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a perfect world where the answer you're asking for is the answer you need,  this:

```
var countryId = $(this).val();
```

would become something like this:

```
var countryName = $("#country option[selected='selected']").text();
```

However, there are a couple things to point out about problems with your code and why you shouldn't take this approach.

- Under most circumstances, you should never join tables on a variable-length field. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3916731/12116036) explains most of the reasons why this is a bad idea, but the main issue is the ability to change the text and making existing foreign keys invalid. For example, let's say you updated `'United State'` to `'United States'` in the countries table. Now, you can no longer link `'California'` and `'Florida'` in the states table back to the countries table, because the `country_id` field still contains `'United State'`. I recommend switching back to your original version of the states table.
- As Nico mentioned in the comments, your code leaves your database vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You might get the false feeling that using POST makes you feel safe, but the reality is someone could easily fake a POST request and delete your entire database. Instead, change your query into a prepared statement, like a stored procedure, and replace the string concatenation with SQL parameters. By feeding your form data into your queries as SQL parameters instead of concatenating a query together, you eliminate the ability for an attacker to run their own queries on the same line.

Example for states:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_states_by_country_id(IN countryId INT(11))
BEGIN
    SELECT id,
           state_name
    FROM states
    WHERE country_id = countryId;
END
```

Calling the stored procedure in PHP:

```
$query = 'CALL get_states_by_country_id(?)';
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
// If your parameter is a string, sanitize the data first!
$stmt->bindParam('i', $_POST['countryId']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Then you would retrieve the data in the same way you currently do. Just don't forget to call `$stmt->close();` when you're done.

Comment: @Micheal i tried var countryName = $("#country option[selected='selected']").text(); and change the Variable name countryName through the code and it is still not fetching data on second dropdown list

Comment: I think something is wrong with the script because i am not getting second value on action.php if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo '<option value="">Select State</option>';

Comment: Did you switch to using a stored procedure like I suggested? If you're still concatenating a query together and using a string id, you have to add quotes to the query around your string: `$query = "SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id = '".$_POST['countryId']."'";` Like I said, though, you really should avoid doing it this way, because it leaves your database vulnerable to SQL injection.